# EFCore Power Tools: The application to execute does not exist: 'contextlist'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-power-tools

I'm using the [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) and am encountering an issue when I try to 'Compare DbContext to Database':

[image]

**I am on version 2.5.636. The following is in the efptparams.txt file**:

```
exec --depsfile "C:\Users\MSE\source\repos\MyProject\Backend\Data\bin\Debug\net5.0\Data.deps.json" --additionalprobingpath "C:\Users\MSE\.nuget\packages" --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --fx-version  "C:\Users\MSE\AppData\Local\Temp\efpt\efpt.dll"  contextlist "C:\Users\MSE\source\repos\MyProject\Backend\Data\bin\Debug\net5.0\Data.dll" "C:\Users\MSE\source\repos\MyProject\Backend\MyProjectAPI\bin\Debug\net5.0\MyProjectAPI.dll"
```

The following is shown in the output window when I try this:

```
System.ArgumentException: Error:
The application to execute does not exist: 'contextlist'

Parameter name: processResult
   at async Task<IEnumerable<string>> EFCorePowerTools.Handlers.Compare.CompareHandler.GetDbContextTypesAsync(string outputPath, Project project) in C:/projects/efcorepowertools/src/GUI/EFCorePowerTools/Handlers/Compare/CompareHandler.cs:line 170
   at async Task EFCorePowerTools.Handlers.Compare.CompareHandler.HandleComparisonAsync(string outputPath, Project project) in C:/projects/efcorepowertools/src/GUI/EFCorePowerTools/Handlers/Compare/CompareHandler.cs:line 84
```

Comment: Please share version in use and the contents of efptparams.txt in your %temp% folder

Comment: @ErikEJ I have eidted the question.

Comment: I have attempted a fix in the latest daily build.

Comment: Do you have the 3.1 runtime installed?

Comment: @ErikEJ I do not think so. I will check out your latest build. Thanks!

Comment: Otherwise I suggest you create a GitHub issue